Measure request to response time with htmx
Using htmx, is there a way to measure the time it took to get a response from the server, starting from the time the request was sent?
My usage is that I have a user typing in a search bar, each new modification of the input text field (throttled at 50ms) triggers a new request to the server to fetch search results. The resulting HTML is then displayed on the page each time the server responds with some results. I would like to write some text with "387 results in 17ms".

But there are two pieces of information in that message; the number of results and the total processing time. The number of results can only come from the server, so there'd be little reason to not let the server measure the processing time as well?

the number of results is indeed sent by the server, but the time it takes to show them is also dependent on the network speed and other small form factors

Yes but the network speed is entirely irrelevant to how fast your server is performing. In fact if you let that be factored into the number, you have no way of knowing if the number is caused by slow software or slow network. If you let the server specify how long it took, say that 17ms, but the in your network tab of your browser's developer tools you see that the request took 500ms to process anyway, you know for a fact something is up with the network.

Agreed. I would expect that "387 results in 17ms" means, that's how much time it took to find results (in db), not including client timeouts, nor request time, those seems irrelevant for the end user I feel and you can always use analytics for inside info.

I think you guys are right. I'm convinced. Closing this question.

The actual answer is to use the beforeRequest and afterRequest events to time it:
<form hx-post=""
      hx-on::before-request="event.detail.xhr.go_time = performance.now()"
      hx-on::after-request="const elapsed = performance.now() - event.detail.xhr.go_time;
                            console.log(`That took ${elapsed} milliseconds.`);">

